# C++ detect if global variable was declared

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use SFINAE like boost's [`has_member`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/boost/convert/detail/has_member.hpp) or other C++ standard complient means to check if a specific variable was declared in global scope?
This means without declaring a macro beforehand to check this or using compiler specific additions like MSVC's __if_exists. GCC like weak symbol declarations are also no option.

A solution using C++11 or earlier would be perfect for me. Other solutions are also welcome.

P.S.: It can be assumed that the type of the variable is known.

Background:
I am currently trying to target many differnent Arduino plattform in a generic way. I know that the special pins are declared as `static const uint8_t` but I do not know if for example `SDA1` or just `SDA` was declared. To support newer targets without writing a new board definition each time I would like to check a given set of possible pins and support those if declared. This should work out of the box with the Arduino IDE, hence no compiler specific features, extra programs or other fancy additions should be used. I know that for most of those variables there is also a macro declared which indicates those present. Nevertheless, the cleaner solution in my point of view is to check directly, whether the pin variable was declared or not, as the macro names tend to be target specific whereas the pin variable name and declaration looks quite stable. The proper solution would be to enfore naming conventions and macro defintions to support such checks, of course. The effort to push idea this to all Arduino core projects is, however, too much for me.

P.P.S: Please do not just down vote or comment this for being a xy-question. My example is just one of many. Any other API like multi-library target project could make use of such a solution as well. Even a clear "no, that's not possible" would save at least a lot of time searching for such a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can best solve this using a build step, such as a configure script that tries to compile code using the global variables in question. It can then determine whether the build fails or succeeds, and define proper makros to handle the cases in question in your code.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I know that this is basically what multi-target libraries and programs do, by using configure scripts or CMake for example. Such an option is, sadly, not included in the current Arduino IDE, as mentioned in OP.

Comment: You don't need to use the IDE. You could use its compiler without the IDE.

Comment: I know and that would work for me but probably not that well for many other users.